# Using a DrawingImage as Icon for Multiple MenuItems

Tags: wpf, image, menuitem, geometrydrawing

I have some icon resources as `DrawingImage`s that is made up of many `GeometryDrawing`s.  I have File `MenuItem`s and `ToolBar` buttons that use these images via resource bindings to `MenuItem.Icon`.  Unfortunately, only one of the `MenuItem`s show the icon.

I am sure you can't assign a single `DrawingImage` resource to many `MenuItem.Icon` (or anything else for that matter), but I don't know of an alternative.  I would prefer not to duplicate the `DrawingImage` resource, but if I have too I guess I will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You assign an Image control to the Icon Property and set the DrawingImage into the Image.Source property.

In XAML:

```
<MenuItem>
    <MenuItem.Icon>
        <Image Source="{StaticResource myDrawingImage}"/>
    </MenuItem.Icon>
    <!-- everyhting else -->
</MenuItem>
```

In C#:

```
menuItem.Icon = new Image() {Source = (ImageSource)Resources["myDrawingImage"]};
```

Comment: Turns out the problem was a mistake in using Image as the Resource element versus the DrawingImage.

I didn't see the forest through the trees